# Switching Audiotrack on Chromecast

Tags: javascript, android, html5-video, html5-audio, chromecast

I actually cannot believe I couldn't find an answer to this as it appears to me as if it should be a common problem - am I using the wrong terminology?

However, I am looking for a way to switch the audiotrack of the video that is being sent to be played on chromecast. More precisely I'm talking about a multitrack video File embedding two audio lines (mkv-format).

I've not found any possibility to do this using the (Android) SDK, nor could I change it using JavaScript on the Receiver App itself. (This would at least enable me to implement the ability using a custom receiver).

From my research I found, that the video element is supposed to get a audioTracks and videoTracks attribute but accordingly it is not yet implemented by any browser and thus obviously not available on chromecast. (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_audiotracks.asp)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the media player library documentation for cycling through audio streams: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player

```
window.changeLanguage = function() {
 var currentLanguage = null;
 var streamCount = this.protocol_.getStreamCount();
 var streamInfo;
 for (var i = 0; i < streamCount; i++) {
   if (protocol.isStreamEnabled(i)) {
     streamInfo = protocol.getStreamInfo(i);
     if (streamInfo.mimeType.indexOf('audio') === 0) {
       if (streamInfo.language) {
         currentLanguage = i;
         break;
       }
     }
   }
 }

 if (currentLanguage === null) {
   currentLanguage = 0;
 }

 i = currentLanguage + 1;
 while (i !== currentLanguage) {
   if (i === streamCount) {
     i = 0;
   }

   streamInfo = protocol.getStreamInfo(i);
   if (streamInfo.mimeType.indexOf('audio') === 0) {
     protocol.enableStream(i, true);
     protocol.enableStream(currentLanguage, false);
     break;
   }

   i++;
 }

 if (i !== currentLanguage) {
   this.player_.reload();
 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - actually I can't believe I overlooked this before posting here. However, if I understand it correctly this uses the protocol object of the MediaPlayer API, which as far as I can see is only available usign the HLS, DASH or SmoothStreaming protocol. Is der a possibility to get an instance of the protocol from the <video> tag if the stream is loaded using normal src attribute? The API is unfortunately not very helpful in this area...

Comment: You can try the HTML video element support for audio tracks: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#media-resources-with-multiple-media-tracks

Comment: As I stated in my original post - the audioTracks attribute seems to not be available yet in any major browser nor on the chromecast... So I guess I'll have to wait for it to be implemented and updated on the chromecast?