# Is the audioTracks element available on the Chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to test mp4 videos with multiple audio tracks on the Chromecast but `audioTracks` appears to be missing from the `video` element. Is there some way for me to switch audio tracks on mp4 videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look on the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes) of Google Cast, it seems that audioTracks is not yet supported on the Cast API. This related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174160) also ask about audioTrack on chromecast, but the owner of the question found out that it is not yet supported. For more information, you can check this [Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) and [Audio Device](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/audio) that is currently or only available for the Cast API.

Comment: Thanks for the info.